# Should I distribute my drives across different SATA controllers?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage, chipset

I have an Asus motherboard which comes with both the AMD SB950 chipset (6 SATA ports) and also an ASMedia 1061 storage controller (2 ports).

I also have:

- 1 SSD drive for Windows
- 1 HDD for Linux
- 2 HDDs for storage
- 1 DVD drive
- 1 External HDD

That makes 5 storage units. Sometimes (somewhat often) I'll have 4 of them busy doing IO operations at the same time. Right now they're all plugged to the SB950 ports, as I read - and tested - it's faster than the ASMedia controller. However the [source benchmark](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/storage-controller-performance-ssd,3540.html), as well as my testing, only covers the scenario where a single drive is being used.

Would it be advisable to re-plug some of the devices to the ASMedia controller, in order to offload the SB950 chipset?

All of the HD drives are SATA-III 7200 rpm. No RAID is used.

Comment: I may put the DVD and External HDD on ASMedia as they aren't much benefited from the boost of SB950 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most gaming / performance MBs have 2 SATA controllers (like AMD/intel): a primary one usually with 4,6 or 8 SATA ports and a secondary one (like a SI).

The primary ones are faster and have better driver support.

My recommendation is to have all HDDs on the primary one. SSD also, except the case if you have a special SATA port for SSDs like a few recent MBs support. All optical units (CD/DVD/BR) or non-permanent HDDs (like a backup HDD you connect from time to time) should be on the secondary controller.